# for some reason, I get an error as soon as I hit the code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

for some reason, I get an error as soon as I hit the code.

```
def skill_list
    array = skill_associations.map do |sa|
     sa.skill.names // this is where I get error  
    end
   array.join(", ")
end

def skill_list=(names)
    self.skill_associations.delete_all
    self.skills = names.split(",").map do |m|
      Skill.where(name: m.strip).first_or_create!
    end
end
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking, try to explain what you are doing, and what you are trying to achieve.
How do you call your methods so that they give you a nil error for example ?

Comment: One of your skill_associations has no skill. that's the cause of the error.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need:

```
skill_associations.map(&:skill).compact.map(&:name).compact.join(", ")
```

Comment: Depending on the actual requirements, this fix can be simply sweeping the problem under the rug.